# How to install LAPACK and BLAS using CYGWIN?

Tags: python, cygwin, lapack, blas

I have a use case for the `pymc` python module.

When doing `python -m pip install pymc`, I yield `[Errno 2] No such file or directory "lapack/double/dpotrs.f"`.

When doing `python -m pip install lapack`, I yield `No matching distribution found for lapack`.

I know that I need the Intel Fortran Compiler and MS Visual Studio, according to [this](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/VisualStudio_install.html) guide.

Because this seems non-trivial to me, I am looking for a quick & simple alternative.

How to install LAPACK and BLAS with CYGWIN?

Comment: LAPACK isn't a python package so `pip` isn't going to have it. I'm afraid there probably is no "quick and simple" alternative.

Comment: Honestly, my advice to you is that if you want to use Python for scientific computing then use the Anaconda Python distribution and the `conda` package manager. This will installing `pymc` a simple `conda install pymc`

Comment: many thanks. does this mean that i need to install all my modules from the non-conda python (windows) again for the conda python?

Comment: Yes, although the Anaconda distribution comes with the whole scipy stack (numpy, pandas, scipy, sklearn, matplotlib, ipython etc) and more already installed.

Comment: have you tried to install the cygwin packages `liblapack0` and `liblapack-devel` ? May be pymc will use them instead of trying to build Blas and Lapack by itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to use Cygwin, you can install `python`, `BLAS`, and `LAPACK` *on* Cygwin quite easily as "Gygwin package".

The documentation at https://cygwin.com/install.html says that you can

> Run setup-x86_64.exe any time you want to update or install a Cygwin package.

Then from the installer, look for and select the entries:

- openblas-0.2.16-1
- lapack-3.6.0r1730-2

Do not forget to install

- python-numpy-1.9.2-1

The installer will also add more package that are essential for those you selected. After that, you should be able to use Pymc from within the Cygwin terminal.

You do not need the Intel compiler and MS Visual Studio at all (and the link that you posted refers to something rather different than using Cygwin).

Comment: Just for those who want to test, create on-line file 'int main(){}' and build it this way: gcc -lblas a.cpp . If blas is missing, you'll get error message.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential failure mode to watch out for, based on my own experience:

Watch out for mistakes with the PATH variable initialization from your .bashrc file.

The numpy module installation and usage depends on the PATH variable.
The installation adds the subpath: '/usr/lib/lapack'

If your .bashrc file is not carefully constructed to 'ADD' subpaths to the existing PATH, an error can occur,

The result is an error during the numpy module import such that the lapack dependencies are not resolved!
i.e.,
after the numpy install, the system should have files:
/usr/lib/lapack/cygblas-0.dll
AND
/usr/lib/lapack/cyglapack-0.dll

If the subpath '/usr/lib/lapack' has been HOSED by your .bashrc file, the obscure loading error is reported.